# How to pack app using Asar but exclude Electron

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, asar

I want to just pack my Electron application to an asar archive, but without the `devDependencies` declared in `package.json`. Actually the only thing I don't need to be packaged to the asar archive is `"node_modules/electron"`, so according to the docs (https://github.com/electron/asar#excluding-multiple-resources-from-being-packed) I've tried:

```
asar pack . app.asar --unpack-dir "{node_modules/electron}"
```

But without succes... It still packs `"node_modules/electron"` to the archive.
How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this worked:

```
asar pack . app.asar --unpack-dir "node_modules/electron" && rd "app.asar.unpacked" /s /q
```